# Superclass of a Java class in separate jar file showing as Object

Tags: java, urlclassloader

I have a class called Passthru, which extends a class called Component, which is held in a jar file.  At run time, I want to load Passthru (using URLClassLoader with one or more jar files, plus optionally a local directory), and then test the superclass against a few possibilities, of which one is Component.  This works great if both Passthru and Component are in the same jar file, even if different packages, but if Passthru is in a *local directory* (with Component in the jar file, as before), doing getSuperClass on Passthru returns Object.  I know Object is in Passthru's parent tree, but in this case I don't seem to be able to find out Passthru's *direct* parent.  I suppose I could go to Passthru's source and scan to find the superclass, but there should be a simpler way...?!

I also noted that in both cases Passthru is loaded with my URLClassLoader, but when Passthru is in the local directory, its parent's loader shows as the "primordial" loader (null) - don't know if this is relevant...

Solved!!  It *was* sort of a dumb question: it turned out that the source code in the directory was back level, and didn't match the code in the jar file.  Also, I hadn't added the directory code as an Eclipse project, so apparently Eclipse compiled this code but didn't give me any error indications, so I didn't see the compile errors "behind the scenes". So when I worked purely in the jar file, everything worked, but when I went to the directory, compile errors prevented the classes there from picking up the Component class. Thanks to the people who responded to my question - sorry if I wasted your time!

Comment: Please attach code?
I can guess you are passing the url of a specific jar (or otherwise a directory which does not contain the jar which Component is in). In such a case URLClassLoader cannot load Component

Comment: Wait, so you're saying you have a class defined as `class Passthru extends Component`, and the code `Passthru.class.getSuperclass()` returns a different result depending on how you package your classes? This seems...not right. I also cannot reproduce this behavior based on the information you've given - something else is going on here.

Comment: Yup!  And the interesting things is that this code worked for literally years...  My guess is that something changed with a recent Java release.  My other thought is that maybe it shouldn't have worked back then, and somebody recently enforced some rule (that I don't know about)!

Comment: In case the last sentence wasn't clear...: I may have been getting away with something that wasn't documented, but worked, e.g. maybe superclasses have to be in the same jar file or directory as the subclass, but there was no test for this.  Later someone supporting Java comes along, and adds a test to prevent superclass and subclass from being in different jar files/directories... thereby breaking my code...  What do you think?

Comment: @PaulMorrison if you solve your own question, post an answer instead of editing the solution into the question